# Make custom legend with Julia Pyplot

Tags: plot, graph, julia

I would like to make a custom legend in Julia's pyplot, in which the legend labels are not necessarily related to individual series plotted on the graph. For example:

[image]

In Python (pyplot comes from matplotlib) this could be done with:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap(0.), lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap(.5), lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color=cmap(1.), lw=4)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = ax.plot(data)
ax.legend(custom_lines, ['Cold', 'Medium', 'Hot'])
```

The issue is I cannot seem to access the Line2D object in pyplot (using pyplot as plt, plt.lines.Line2D does not work).

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not `pyplot` but `MakieLayout` will solve your problem:

[image]

Link to the [example](http://juliaplots.org/MakieReferenceImages/gallery//manual_legend/index.html) with code.

I got the answer from [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/common-legend-using-layouts/45553/5).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with the existing answer, but I managed to figure it out. Per the [PyPlot.jl docs](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl) under Exported Functions,

> (And the raw PyObject for the matplotlib modules is also accessible as PyPlot.matplotlib.)

So you can achieve your goal by just putting the full call in (I assign to a variable to avoid making the custom_lines ugly):

```
L2D = PyPlot.matplotlib.lines.Line2D
custom_lines = [L2D([0], [0], color=cmap(0.), lw=4),
                L2D([0], [0], color=cmap(.5), lw=4),
                L2D([0], [0], color=cmap(1.), lw=4)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = ax.plot(data)
ax.legend(custom_lines, ['Cold', 'Medium', 'Hot'])
```